# How can I allow another user to move files around a shared folder in OneDrive?

Tags: file-sharing, onedrive, digital-signature

I have setup a Shared folder on my Onedrive account for my team to facilitate document sign off however after a member of the team signs the document they can not move the document to the next persons folder within the shared folder. The user was given full permission both Read and Write when sharing the link.

The shared link is saved as a weblink on their pc as not all of them have Onedrive accounts.

The goal of the system is to create a simple temporary e-signature system between multiple organisations that does not increase cost due to some of the smaller organisations limited resources. The userbase consists of some very basic technically skilled employees who do not have and have not used office 365.

Comment: Why not use a proper tool like Sharepoint for this?

Comment: As it is a multi-organisational team and not all the members have office 365 and know how to use sharepoint.

Comment: Using a proper collaboration plattform might still be a good idea. Using Sharepoint isn't any more complex than using OneDrive. As you mention needing an account that's also likely the reason they can't do certain things. Allowing editing for everyone with a link will limit what people can do. Using actual contacts should enable people to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Using the sharing option of specific people rather than anyone with a link should enable the missing options.

See e.g. [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/onedrive-for-business/cannot-delete-shared-files/m-p/2089615) as a pointer towards this behavior. I was also able to confirm it. Using just allowing anyone with a link to allow editing a folder resulted in not being able to delete or move files. Using specific people sharing did.

It might be possible to influence this behavior by using enterprise policies. A possible alternative might be to use Power Automate.